# How to make jenkins sends email alarm of disk full?

Tags: jenkins

One day, I found my jenkins server had not worked since 20 days ago because of disk full.

Is there any way to make Jenkins notify me by email if it cannot work because of disk full?

Answer (score 2):

The [**Disk Usage Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disk+Usage+Plugin) has options to email when space falls below certain threshold. Once installed, you can find the relevant configuration under Global Configuration for Jenkins.

1. Go to your `http://[JENKINS_URL]/configure`
2. Scroll down to "Disk Usage" section
3. Click "Warn if some size is exceeded"
4. Enter email
5. Click "Warn if all jobs exceed some size"
6. Enter the size that you don't want to exceed

Comment: The plugin looks nice and there are some warning options but I can't find anyone to warn lack of free space.

Comment: Edited answer with direct instructions

Comment: @Slave  Do we need to configure SMTP for this ?

Comment: @vijay yes, any email functionality requires preconfigured smtp